# Making a CHECK CONSTRAINT with OR in postgres SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, constraints

I'm wondering if it's possible to evaluate some conditions in a CHECK CONSTRAINT first and then do an OR with another expression.

My situation:

4 Tables:\

- main, which an id, a type variable(lets make it a smallint of 0-2), and foreign keys to the following tables:
- a, b, and c, which only contain an id

I would want to make a check constraint which basically follows the following logic:

```
if main.type = 0:
    main.a != NULL
    main.b = NULL
    main.c = NULL
elif main.type = 2:
    main.a = NULL
    main.b = NULL
    main.c != NULL
```

if the type = 1 I don't care what is filled in.

I tried doing a CHECK CONSTRAINT like so:

```
CHECK((main.type = 0 AND main.a != NULL AND main.b = NULL AND main.c = NULL) OR
(main.type = 2 AND main.a = NULL AND main.b = NULL AND main.c != NULL))
```

The problem is that the inner parentheses get deleted/ ignored after applying this constraint which means it becomes mostly nonsense and it doesn't work.

Is this possible to solve with a CHECK CONSTRAINT or should a trigger be used for this?

Comment: The brackets are deleted because AND always has a higher precedence than OR, so they are logically redundant (although good for readability). I think Postgres stores the computed plan of the constraint, not the text you enter, so when you get back a textual representation it's in a kind of "normalised" form. As Gordon Linoff points out, this isn't actually your problem; your problem is that the logic is handling NULLs wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`!= NULL`!  That is not going to work.  This seems to be the logic you want:

```
CHECK ( (type = 0 and a is not null and b is null and c is null) or
        (type = 2 and a is null and b is null and c is not null) or
        (type = 1)
      )
```

Comment: Cool, I'll try it out.

What if when type  = 1 I don't care if either a, b, or c is filled in but it should be only one of them?

Comment: @Blanen This answer is the correct answer to the **posted** question. Now you change the question. Do not do it. In instead accept the answer and open another question.

Comment: @Blanen . . . If you have another question, ask it as another question.